# Creating COM interface pointer works on development machine but causes application crash on other machine

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, mfc, com

I am using COM interop to call a method in a C# dll from a C++ application.

The C# code is:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("f08942b1-db20-44aa-9713-7d28fff51e2b")]
  public interface IMyLibraryInterface
  {
    string POSRequest(string request);
  }

  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("4d962dd5-05ed-431b-82e2-378aebe8d0dc")]
  public class MyLibraryInterface : IMyLibraryInterface
  {
    public string myRequest(string request)
    {
      ....
      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

The calling C++ code is:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
MyLibrary::IMyLibraryInterfacePtr MyLibraryInterface(__uuidof(MyLibrary::MyLibraryInterface));
myResult = (LPCTSTR) MyLibraryInterface->myRequest(myInput);
CoUninitialize();
```

where the relevant tlb file has been imported:

```
#import "MyLibrary.tlb"
```

This works both when debugging and running a release version from my development machine, but causes the application to crash when I run this from another machine. Specifically, the line creating the pointer appears to be the issue:

```
MyLibrary::IMyLibraryInterfacePtr MyLibraryInterface(__uuidof(MyLibrary::MyLibraryInterface));
```

It seems like something is perhaps missing on the other machine but I can't figure out what?

Comment: Did you register the C# COM dll on the other machine?  You have to use the `regasm.exe` to register the dll.

Comment: is the dll in the project's working directory, or placed somewhere on the new machine where the program you made can access it?

Comment: I didn't know that I needed to register the C# dll. Will I need to do this every time that this gets installed?

Comment: @tj_ush - That is how COM works. You should read up on COM if you are going to have to use it, but basically you register the DLL, then when you make the calls in your code, it goes to the registry table and looks to find the DLL. That is why I suggested the other code snippet, if you get any HRESULT but SUCCESS, then something went wrong and you can log it and check it to try to figure it out.  So, in answer to the question, yes. When you install your dll you need to register it.

Comment: The fact you have to register COM to use it is also a good reason to avoid it if possible :).

Comment: If you don't want to register COM first, you can use the **registration free** COM model for say xcopy deployments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: @MickyD - Thats a good point, I had forgotten about that, and I have used reg free COM in some deployments.  I am just glad that it has been years since I have had to deal with COM.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Guess we better toss Office, DirectX, Visual Studio shell, Windows Shell, ADO, Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: Thanks @pstrjds, I'll look at some way of automating it. I've (thankfully) never had to use COM before, but have been lumped working with some old code!

Comment: @tj_ush - That is how/why I learned to work with COM, and learned more than I ever wanted to know...

Comment: @tj_ush - If you are going to have to work with a legacy code base that uses COM, try to find a copy of [Don Box's "Essential COM"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/919597.Essential_Com). I found it extremely helpful when I started doing COM programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a dll that exposes a COM interface, that dll needs to be registered.  The tool for registering a C# COM dll is regasm.exe.  As part of your install process you need to call regasm on any dll that exposes a COM interface.  As part of debugging and helping yourself, you can modify your code slightly to be able to check the HRESULT when you try to create the object, and log if needed.
**Note**: I don't have the setup to test this code, so their may be a typo, but it should point you in the right direction.  If you don't have the "smart pointers" that VS creates, you can use the CoCreateInstance call to create your object and then check the HRESULT from that call.

```
IMyLibraryInterfacePtr myIntPtr = null;
HRESULT hRes = myIntPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyLibrary::MyLibr‌aryInterface));
if (!(SUCCEEDED(hRes))
{
    // This means an error occurred, you can log it for debugging, etc.
}
```

**Edit**
Based on the comment from MickyD, and for sake of completion, there is a way to use COM without [registering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) the dlls. It involves creating manifest files that live alongside the application.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the plug too :)

Comment: @MickyD - Credit where credit due! You sparked my memory. I had forgotten about the regfree COM stuff, now I am recalling spending hours pouring through Don Box's book "Essential COM"...not sure those are happy memories though. Note: This is not a slam against the book, that book was exceptional at helping me to understand COM, just not sure working with COM is a happy memory.

Comment: Thank you good sir.  I had a ton of COM and DCOM (save me!) books from Wrox Press....those large red cover tomes of goodness.   Yes, there are easier ways to do things now :)

Comment: If your setup is InnoSetup then it is quite easy to register your assemblies.